# An identity involving the Pochhammer symbol

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factorial, pochhammer-symbol

I need help proving the following identity:
$$\frac{(6n)!}{(3n)!} = 1728^n \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)_n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)_n.$$
Here,
$$(a)_n = a(a + 1)(a + 2) \cdots (a + n - 1), \quad n > 1, \quad (a)_0 = 1,$$
is the Pochhammer symbol. I do not really know how one converts expressions involving factorials to products of the Pochhammer symbols. Is there a general procedure? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried inducting on n?  If you divide each side by the corresponding terms for n-1 things get much easier.  In general $(a)_n/(a)_{n-1} = a-n+1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pochhammer symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) (sometimes) indicate *rising* factorials, i.e., $n!=(1)_n$ . This is obviously the case here, since the left hand side is never negative, assuming natural *n*.

$$\bigg(\frac16\bigg)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac16+k\bigg)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{6k+1}6\bigg)=6^{-n}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6k+1)$$

$$\bigg(\frac12\bigg)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac12+k\bigg)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{6k+3}6\bigg)=6^{-n}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6k+3)$$

$$\bigg(\frac56\bigg)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac56+k\bigg)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{6k+5}6\bigg)=6^{-n}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6k+5)$$

Since $1728=12^3$, our product becomes $$2^{3n}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6k+1)(6k+3)(6k+5)=\dfrac{2^{3n}\cdot(6n)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6k+2)(6k+4)(6k+6)}=$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{3n}\cdot(6n)!}{2^{3n}\cdot\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k+3)}=\dfrac{(6n)!}{(3n)!}$$

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By using the formula 
\begin{align}
(a)_{kn} = k^{kn} \prod_{r=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac{a+r}{k} \right)_{n}
\end{align}
it is evident that the desired quantity,
\begin{align}
(1728)^{n} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{3}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)_{n},
\end{align}
can be seen as
\begin{align}
2^{6n} 3^{3n} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{3}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)_{n} = \frac{ 6^{6n} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{2}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{3}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)_{n} }{ 3^{3n} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)_{n} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)_{n} } = \frac{(1)_{6n}}{(1)_{3n}} = \frac{(6n)!}{(3n)!}.
\end{align}

Comment: Do you have a reference for this formula?

Comment: The books by E. D. Rainville "Special Functions" or H. M. Srivastava and L. Manocha "A Treatise on Generating Functions" have the generalized Pochammer product formula.

Comment: Please strive not to [vote to reopen](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1931920) dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)

Answer (score 3):

$$1728^n \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)_n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)_n=24^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(6k+1)(2k+1)(6k+5)}=\\=\frac{4^n}{3^n n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(6k+1)(6k+3)(6k+5)(6k+6)}=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(6k+1)(6k+2)(6k+3)(6k+4)(6k+5)(6k+6)}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k+3)}}=\frac{(6n)!}{(3n)!}$$